# Does DynamoDB has support for Tombstone Record handling?

Tags: database, concurrency, amazon-dynamodb

How do we handle the case in dynamoDB when there is a older put request for a key for which there has been a newer delete operation already performed.

Since the newer delete operation has already deleted the record, the older put request can simply write the record again which is not correct.

Does DynamoDB save any metadata for recently deleted records?
Is there any way to handle this case in DynamoDB? Or anyone has any suggestion how to handle this case.

I am using high level DynamoDBMapper instead of low level API.

Comment: I'm not sure if I followed: you want to keep track of every primary key you've deleted so that those keys are never inserted again, is that it?

Comment: @RenatoByrro yes correct. That I want to achieve without having an extra attribute in the table. Also I can not use TTL attribute for this use case, as I already have a TTL attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamo doesn't keep any 'metadata' about what has been previously deleted. Considering you can't create a new attribute to keep track of deleted status, the only two ways I can think for you to handle this are:

## Option 1: create your own 'metadata' table

Create a separate table to keep track of everything you deleted. You'd have a `main` table where you store your regular data, and a `main_deleted` table, where you store only `primary_keys` that have been deleted from the `main` table.

Before inserting any item in the `main` table, check for the `primary_key` in the `main_deleted` table. If it's there, do not proceed with the insert.

## Option 2: use the range_key

If your items have a sort key, you could use it to flag items as deleted without creating a new attribute. Suppose you have this item where the range_key is a UNIX timestamp:

```
{
    "primary_key": "example",
    "timestamp": 1234567890,
    "other": "stuff"
}
```

Instead of deleting the item `primary_key=example`, remove all its attributes and set the `timestamp` to a value that you'd never use for regular items, such as `0`. When inserting or updating items in the table, use a condition expression or query the database previously to check if the item was not deleted before (in other words, `timestamp=0`).

I'm sure there will be plenty of other ways and maybe (or probably) those two above aren't the best ones. Use your creativity! ;)

Comment: I have taken somewhat similar approach of making one of my attribute as empty and increasing my TTL. Even I could not find a better solution owing to my use case in the downstream app which will consume this table.

Comment: As far as I know, you'd have this issue in any database. I'm not aware of a DB that does exactly what you want out of the box... You'll need to implement this constraint yourself, either on the application level, DB level or a mix of both.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `ConditionExpression` to check whether the data is already exists before updating (i.e. putting) the item. Both `UpdateItem` and `PutItem` have `ConditionExpression` to check some condition before performing the action.

Refer this [conditional writes](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-improved-conditional-writes-in-dynamodb/)

In your case, you need to check whether the `hash key` exists before performing the update operation.

Comment: This won't work. The condition will always pass, since the item has been deleted previously, and the `PutItem` will succeed, which is the exact thing he wants to avoid...

Comment: If the item is deleted, the hash key wouldn't exist right?

Comment: Correct. And he wants a ways to know that this key existed in the past, so that it's not inserted again.